# Azure Mobile Offline Sync: Cannot delete an operation from __operations

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm having a huge issue that I've been trying for days to get through. I have a scenario in which I'm trying to handle an Insert Conflict in my Xamarin project. The issue is that the record in the Cloud DB doesn't exist because there was an issue with a foreign key constraint so I'm in a scenario in which the sync conflict handler needs to delete the local record along with the record in the __operations table in SQLite. I've tried *everything*. Purge with the override set to 'true' so that it *should* delete the local record and all operations associated. Doesn't work. I've been just trying to force delete it by accessing the SQL store manually:

```
var id = localItem[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Id];
var operationQuery = await store.ExecuteQueryAsync("__operations", $"SELECT * FROM __operations WHERE itemId = '{id}'", null).ConfigureAwait(false);
var syncOperation = operationQuery.FirstOrDefault();
var tableName = operation.Table.TableName;

await store.DeleteAsync(tableName, new List<string>(){ id.ToString() });

if (syncOperation != null)
{
    await store.DeleteAsync("__operations", new List<string>() { syncOperation["id"].ToString() }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I am able to query the __operations table and I can see the ID of the item I want to delete. The DeleteAsync method runs without exception but no status is returned so I have no idea if this worked or not. When I try to sync again the operation stubbornly exists. This seems *ridiculous*. How do I just delete an operation without having to sync with the web service? I'm about to dig down further and try to force it even harder by using the SQLiteRaw library but I'm really really hoping I'm missing something obvious? Can anyone help? THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a subclass of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncHandler class, which overrides OnPushCompleteAsync() in order to handle conflicts and other errors. Let's call the class SyncHandler:

```
public class SyncHandler : MobileServiceSyncHandler
{
    public override async Task OnPushCompleteAsync(MobileServicePushCompletionResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            await ResolveConflictAsync(error);
        }
        await base.OnPushCompleteAsync(result);
    }

    private static async Task ResolveConflictAsync(MobileServiceTableOperationError error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Resolve Conflict for Item: {error.Item} vs serverItem: {error.Result}");

        var serverItem = error.Result;
        var localItem = error.Item;

        if (Equals(serverItem, localItem))
        {
            // Items are the same, so ignore the conflict
            await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(serverItem);
        }
        else // check server item and local item or the error for criteria you care about
        {
            // Cancels the table operation and discards the local instance of the item.
            await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Include an instance of this SyncHandler() when you initialize your MobileServiceClient:

```
        await MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new SyncHandler()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Read up on the [`MobileServiceTableOperationError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.sync.mobileservicetableoperationerror?view=azure-dotnet) to see other conflicts you can handle as well as its methods to allow resolving them.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. You're a life saver!